# Broken iron-flex-layout dependency

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a simplistic page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
  </head>

  <body class="fullbleed vertical layout" unresolved> 
    <div>Alpha</div>
    <div class="flex">Beta (flex)</div>
    <div>Gamma</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is very near from there given samples for iron-flex-layout.
But it renders an empty page.
If I add another import, like iron-image, the page is displayed correctly.
It is served by polyserve, and everything is correctly installed otherwise.

Thanks for your help / explanation.

Comment: snippet works fine for me - I see
Alpha
Beta (flex)
Gamma
Maybe some local glitch?

Comment: the iron-flex-layout.html location looks quite strange - where that "classes" dir comes from? In my projects it's bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html

Comment: @user656449: stated in the docs https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout in "Using layout classes".

Comment: @user656449: I used the code snippet for formatting. It's not supposed to work without an http server. It should display alpha on top, gamma on bottom and beta filling in between.

Answer (score 0):

My bad here.

At this point `unresolved` body attribute is not defined. 
Removing it makes it work as expected.

No clue where this attribute is defined, though (but importing an element such as iron-element, as mentioned above, and its dependencies makes it defined)